# What's the proper way to add my dynamic home IP to AWS RDS Firewall?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Normally I just add my home IP address to the security group of my AWS RDS instance.  But over time this is a problem because my IP address changes once in awhile and my security group gets all these old IP addresses that I can't remember if they were my home IP or a valid work IP.

Is there a better way to handle this?  Or is the only option to just buy a static IP address from my ISP?

Answer (score 1):

Since AWS exposes all the functionality via APIs you can update your IP periodically. I had the exact same issue some time ago and wrote myself a Powershell script to update the security groups with my current external IP. I blogged about it here if you're interested: [Update AWS Security Groups with PowerShell](http://volkanpaksoy.com/archive/2014/12/12/update-aws-security-groups-with-powershell/)

And here is the Gist for my Powershell script:

https://gist.github.com/volkanx/e78dfd1ab3acf220eff8

You can fiddle the script to suit your needs. My script is for EC2 security groups but the idea is similar.